# Can QGIS 3.10.2 w GDAL 3.0 be installed on Ubuntu 18.04 (without being experimental)?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu

I just updated QGIS on Ubuntu 18.04 but it didn't update GDAL to 3x, instead it is still at

`Running against GDAL/OGR 2.2.3`

Is this the correct situation?

Without going into an experimental *bleeding edge* scenario, can GDAL 3x be put in there?

ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the most straight-forward way to get GDAL3.x on Ubuntu 18.04 would be to add the ubuntu-gis PPA to your software sources (which, at the time of writing, would provide you with GDAL 3.0.4): [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable)

You could do that with the following commands:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, this PPA is described as:

> These releases are more bleeding edge and while generally they should work well, they don't receive the same amount of quality assurance as our stable releases do.

The expression "bleeding edge" is in there, which is exactly what you are *not* looking for, but I believe this PPA is the best way to get it going, and the benefit of it is that you get a coherent set of packages that other people are also using and testing (instead of doing your own tinkering), so you don't have to worry about potential issues with dependencies / incompatibilities as much.

If you really don't want to take risks and prefer sticking to the distribution's default packages, you could move to the next LTS, Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa), which includes GDAL 3.0.4 by default: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gdal-bin

Comment: Hey thanks, going to Ubuntu 20.04 might be the go. Ta

Comment: Do let us know how you go!

Comment: Upgraded to 20.04, it's there OK.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you think it solved your issue!